# Copy a content type from another site

Tags: 8, nodes

I am the owner of 2 sites that are running Drupal 8. In Site[X] I have *news* nodes.
In Site[Y], I want to automatically get all the *news* nodes that are posted on Site[X] (title, body, images etc.).

Scenario:

1. Site[X] making new content (news) article
2. Site[Y] checking for new nodes, copying them, and saving them in the database to show them on Site[Y]

How can I do this the best/easiest/safest way in Drupal 8, with what methods, languages and how do I start?

Comment: content type(and fields) are config so that is easy but content itself has to be migrated, so you will have to write a migration plugin with site X DB being the source and run it via cron or something).

Answer (score 0):

Although not yet a full release for D8, [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) is perfect for this type of thing.

That said if you have the know-how, when saving a node, you could post to the second site, and consume the data using the built-in REST API.